# java.io.filenotfoundexception: /home/ljh/.android/analytics.settings (permission denied)

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

When I started Android studio, I got

> could not initialize analytics, treating as opt-out. java.io.filenotfoundexception: /home/ljh/.android/analytics.settings (permission denied)

What should I do? My OS is Ubuntu 32bit

Comment: if you're getting a permission denied error, maybe you should check your file and folder permissions on the file specified?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to install these 32 bit libraries on your ubuntu box

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get -qqy update
sudo apt-get -qqy install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

Following are compile errors which are solved by issuing above commands :

```
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources
   Building Cordova app for Android          \
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
 FAILEDding Cordova app for Android          \

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

stack trace may also show these errors

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 37.372 secs
%% Command finished with error code 1: /home/stens/src/github.com/loudthink/loudspeed/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildRelease,-b,/home/stens/src/github.com/loudthink/loudspeed/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

   While building Cordova app for platform Android:
   Error: /home/stens/src/github.com/loudthink/loudspeed/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1
   Error output:
   Could not initialize analytics, treating as opt-out.
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/stens/.android/analytics.settings (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has root permission, and not your user's.

You can see how in second command, root is the owner of folder.
I changed it to my user, and it works.

```
lucas@ubuntu$ ls /home/lucas/.android/
ls: no se puede abrir el directorio '/home/lucas/.android/': Permiso denegado

lucas@ubuntu$ ls -lart /home/lucas/ | grep android
drwxr-x---   2 root root     4096 sep 14 14:02 .android

lucas@ubuntu$ sudo chown lucas:lucas /home/lucas/.android/
[sudo] password for lucas: 
Fingerprint Login 1.09
Authenticating lucas
Swipe your finger or type your password:

lucas@ubuntu$ ls /home/lucas/.android/
adbkey  adbkey.pub  analytics.settings
lucas@LUCAS-ITECNIS:~/itecnis/simple/usuarios$ ls -lart /home/lucas/ | grep android
drwxr-x---   2 lucas lucas     4096 sep 14 14:02 .android
```